# What is octave "find()"-ing?

Tags: octave

`day[]` is essentially several years worth of [1:365 1:365 1:365 ...] with lots of holes. Length is 5556.

`find()`-ing individual days, thus

```
find(2 == day)'
ans =
 Columns 1 through 13:
    364    729   1094   1460   1825   2190   2555   2921   3286   3651   4016   4382   4747
 Columns 14 and 15:
   5095   5459
>> find(3 == day)'
ans =
 Columns 1 through 13:
    365    730   1095   1461   1826   2191   2556   2922   3287   3652   4017   4383   4748
 Columns 14 and 15:
   5096   5460
>> find(4 == day)'
ans =
 Columns 1 through 13:
      1    366    731   1096   1462   1827   2192   2557   2923   3288   3653   4018   4384
 Columns 14 through 16:
   4749   5097   5461
```

returns reasonable index values, but I don't understand the results of

```
find(2:4 == day)'
ans =
 Columns 1 through 11:
     364     729    1094    1460    1825    2190    2555    2921    3286    3651    4016
 Columns 12 through 22:
    4382    4747    5095    5459    5921    6286    6651    7017    7382    7747    8112
 Columns 23 through 33:
    8478    8843    9208    9573    9939   10304   10652   11016   11113   11478   11843
 Columns 34 through 44:
   12208   12574   12939   13304   13669   14035   14400   14765   15130   15496   15861
 Columns 45 and 46:
   16209   16573
```

Since the length of `day[]` is 5556, what is being returned?

Comment: Please don't edit "solved" into the title. Instead, accept the answer if it solved your problem, or write your own and accept it if you found a different solution. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `day` is a column vector. If not, that statement should error out.

I recommend that you execute that statement in parts: run just `2:4 == day`. This should be a 5556x3 matrix, where the first column is true where `day==2`, the second column `day==3`, etc.

`find` just returns the (linear) indices if the true elements.